# matlab imwrite new image instead of overriding it

Tags: image, matlab, loops, if-statement

I have function that checks for bottle cap. If there is no cap detected, it writes it as an image into folder. My problem is that if I pass different image, the old one get overridden with new one, is there a way to make new image instead of overwriting old one such as nocap0,jpg, then new one nocap1.jpg etc?

Code:

```
function [  ] = CHECK_FOR_CAP( image )

%crop loaction of cap
imageCROP = imcrop(image,[130 0 100 50]);
%turn to BW
imageBW=im2bw(imageCROP);
%count black pixels
answer = sum(sum(imageBW==0));
%if <250 black, save it to folder NOCAP
if answer<250
    imwrite(image, 'TESTINGFOLDERS/NOCAP/nocap.jpg', 'jpg');
    disp('NO CAP DETECTED');
end
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the code a bit now. Everytime I give a different image it now writes new one, BUT it overwrites the previous one aswell like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x4AI.jpg

My new code:

```
function [  ] = CHECK_FOR_CAP( image )

folder = 'TESTINGFOLDERS/NOCAP';
filePattern = fullfile(folder, '/*.*');
ImageFiles = dir(filePattern);
%crop loaction of cap
imageCROP = imcrop(image,[130 0 100 50]);
%turn to BW
imageBW=im2bw(imageCROP);
%count black pixels
answer = sum(sum(imageBW==0));
%if <250 black, save it to folder NOCAP
if answer<250
     a = length(ImageFiles)-1;
    for j = 1:a
        baseFileName = [num2str(j),'.jpg'];
        filename = fullfile(folder,baseFileName);
        if exist(filename,'file')
            imwrite(image,filename);
        end
        imwrite(image, fullfile(filename));
    end
    disp('NO CAP DETECTED');
end
```

Comment: You can use `exist(filename,'file')` to check whether a file already exists. Then you could test for filenames until you found one that isn't taken. Like loop through `i` for `filename=sprintf('TESTINGFOLDERS/NOCAP/nocap%d.jpg',i)`.

Comment: Hi Florian, thank you for reply, I've edited the code, but is still not working correctly. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Since it's too long to put in a comment, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
for j = 1:a
    baseFileName = [num2str(j),'.jpg'];
    filename = fullfile(folder,baseFileName);
    if exist(filename,'file')
        imwrite(image,filename);
    end
    imwrite(image, fullfile(filename));
end
```

This means that whenever you find a file, you overwrite it. Then you overwrite it again. You do this for as many files as exist (`a` comes from some dir you do on your folder). What you want is the opposite: find one that does not exist. Something like this:

```
j = 0;
while true
    j = j + 1;
    baseFileName = [num2str(j),'.jpg'];
    filename = fullfile(folder,baseFileName);
    if ~exist(filename,'file')
        break
    end
end
imwrite(image, fullfile(filename));
```

This could be further shortened (e.g., by looping `while exist(...)`) but it conveys the idea...

Comment: Worked beautifully, Thank you for explaining so simply :)!